# How to get string after last comma in a field

Tags: python, split, substring

I have a column with data like this that I'm accessing via Python:

```
501,555,570=3.5
```

I want to get `570=3.5`.

How can I do that? Would it be a variation of the split command?

Comment: Yes, `split()` should work.

Comment: @gtlambert: Was the downgrade due to my not putting the sample data in a special code block?

Comment: I didn't downvote you! I just improved the formatting of your code

Comment: @jazzime: Downvotes usually come to questions where authors fail to do basic research before asking.

Comment: Ok, I've done basic research but didn't see an example of choosing text after the last comma. I saw several examples where there was just one comma. Could someone provide an example in which the text after the last comma is extracted? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `str.rsplit()` function as follows:

```
In [34]: s = '501,555,570=3.5'

In [35]: s.rsplit(',', 1)[1]
Out[35]: '570=3.5'
```

Comment: I think all the answers provided worked but as you are first, I've indicated this is the correct answer. However, I did test the s.split(',') approach which also produced the same results. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 9):

```
 >>> s = '501,555,570=3.5'
 >>> s.split(",")[-1]
 '570=3.5'
```

This will access the last element in the split string. It is not dependent on how many commas are in the string.

Example of longer string:

```
>>> s = "501,555,670,450,1,12,570=3.5"
>>> s.split(",")[-1]
'570=3.5'
```

Answer (score 4):

A slight variation of wim's answer, if you're in a recent Python 3 version:

```
>>> s = '501,555,570=3.5'
>>> *others, last = s.split(',')
>>> last
'570=3.5'
```

Comment: or just ``last = s.split(',')[-1]`` to access the last element.

Comment: very nice, I used it : )

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = '501,555,570=3.5'
>>> others, last = s.rsplit(',', 1)
>>> last
'570=3.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation, and how I would do it myself:

```
>>> s = '501,555,570=3.5'
>>> last = s.split(',')[-1]
>>> last
'570=3.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) and as @ MartijnPieters♦ mentioned here in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118265/dot-notation-string-manipulation/35118430#comment59006613_35118430).

> for a single split, [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) is going to be faster.

```
>>> s.rpartition(',')[-1]
'570=3.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take substring from the position after where you find the last comma.

```
s[s.rfind(',') + 1 : ]
```